# .htaccess to allow @fontface

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I am using the master .htaccess from [http://docs.joomla.org](http://docs.joomla.org/Htaccess_examples_%28security%29)

Its working well but its also locking out all my `woff|eot|svg|ttf`

How can I add these to the allowed filetypes?
My fonts reside in `/templates/mytemplate/css/type/` folder

Comment: I don't see any rule that would lock out your font files. Do the font's work without the rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the line in question:

```
## Allow limited access for certain Joomla! system directories with client-accessible content
RewriteRule ^(components|modules|plugins|templates)/([^/]+/)*([^/.]+\.)+(jp(e?g|2)?|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|html?|mp(eg?|[34])|avi|wav|og[gv]|xlsx?|docx?|pptx?|zip|rar|pdf|xps|txt|7z|svg|od[tsp]|flv|mov)$ - [L]
```

Basically, in certain folders - including the templates/ folder, only certain file types are being allowed and your files aren't in the list. Adding them in the final bracketed clause pipe separated should do the job. Something like...

```
RewriteRule ^(components|modules|plugins|templates)/([^/]+/)*([^/.]+\.)+(jp(e?g|2)?|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|html?|mp(eg?|[34])|avi|wav|og[gv]|xlsx?|docx?|pptx?|zip|rar|pdf|xps|txt|7z|svg|od[tsp]|flv|mov|woff|eot|svg|ttf)$ - [L]
```

Comment: 404 - Component not found when I check firebug.

Comment: Still not working.. same results as before.

Comment: What happens if you remove the .htaccess file temporarily - or just revert to a bog standard Joomla .htaccess file? Are you sure the files are where you think they are?

Comment: The actual problem is within the following block from the joomla master htaccess 'RewriteRule ^(cache|includes|language|libraries|logs|tmp)/ - [F]'      ----> font awesome has probably stopped working due to your template needing something in 'libraries' - this seems to only be needed by firefox - Internet Explorer is not affected. The solution is to add in the line immediately proceeding the above 'RewriteRule ^(libraries/my-template-framework)($|/) - [L]'  - adding this plus 'woff|eot|svg|ttf' to the front-end rewrite rule fixed font awesome.